# Swift collectionViewCells are not showing

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I have got this Swift code
`

```
let cellId="cellId"

class FeedController: UICollectionViewController{
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    navigationItem.title = "Centill"

    collectionView?.reloadData()
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.95, alpha: 1)
    collectionView?.register(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 3
}
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath);
    cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
    return cell
}

}

class FeedCell: UICollectionViewCell {

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setupViews()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
func setupViews(){
    backgroundColor = .yellow
}
}
```

`
But unfortunately my cells are not showing.It only shows navigation bar and background color.what may be the problem with my code?

Comment: Are you working with storyboard prototype cell ?

Comment: @NiravD no i have deleted storyboard

Comment: Have you register the cell?

Comment: @NiravD `collectionView?.register(FeedCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)`

Comment: Put the reload call after the register of cell

Comment: @NiravD unfortunately it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

Try it. 
You add in the class

```
UICollectionViewDataSource and UICollectionVIewDelegate.
```

Comment: Those classes are automatic in `UICollectionViewController`

Comment: yes but try it. I will try to find your problem in code

Comment: Redundant conformance of 'FeedController' to protocol 'UICollectionViewDataSource'

Comment: try this  dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
    self.collectionView.reloadData() }

instead of

    self.collectionView.reloadData()

Comment: can you sent the screen shot

Comment: Please check any view is hiding your collectionview in main story board

Comment: How can i check that? i showed you my whole code there is no view except navigationbar

Comment: you create a collectionview programmatically in set the x,y position and height and width

Comment: `cell.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 200, width: 400, height: 500)` didn't work

Comment: I add the another answer this coding used to create UIcollectionview

Answer (score 0):

Try This code:

```
    let layout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 20, left: 10, bottom: 10, right: 10)
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 60, height: 60)

    let myCollectionView:UICollectionView = UICollectionView(frame: self.view.frame, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    myCollectionView.dataSource = self
    myCollectionView.delegate = self
    myCollectionView.registerClass(UICollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "MyCell")
    myCollectionView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    self.view.addSubview(myCollectionView)
```

Comment: Please refer this url   http://swiftdeveloperblog.com/code-examples/create-uicollectionview-in-swift-programmatically/

Comment: This url in swift 3.0   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39438803/how-to-create-uicollectionviewcell-programmatically

Comment: My code's class is `UICollectionViewController` not `UIViewController`

Comment: Try this url     https://www.raywenderlich.com/136159/uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started

Answer (score 0):

In your cellForItemAt dataSource method you need to give custom UICollectionCell Class

```
let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath) as! FeedCell
cell.backgroundColor = .yellow
return cell
```

Then you will able to see cell.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the size for collection view cell. add the below code snippet

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    // calculate and return the height
}
```